# virsh shutdown for OpenBSD (libvirt/kvm)

Tags: qemu, kvm, acpi, openbsd, libvirt

Is it possible to correctly shutdown a openbsd 4.7 or 4.9 with

```
virsh shutdown OpenBSD
```

The openbsd is under kvm/qemu configured from libvirt.

shutdown should send an ACPI signal "Power button pressed", but my openbsd guest does not react to this.

Also, can I configure OpenBSD to really turn off power of virtual machine when doing `halt`? Now it asks user from console "press any key to reboot" and don't switch power off.

Answer (score 1):

did you try?

```
# shutdown -hp now
```

I did that *in* my openbsd machine, logged through ssh and it works fine. The machine is shutdown and virsh shows that too.

```
virsh # list --all
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
  - CentOS_6             shut off
  - openbsd              shut off
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "halt -p" to power down the VM after the OS is halted.

I have not been able to get OpenBSD 4.7 or 4.9 to respond to ACPI signals on KVM/QEMU that ships with Ubuntu Jaunty (9.04).

Answer (score 1):

There's neither paravirt driver nor agent (qemu guest agent) in OpenBSD. But see [acpibtn(4)](http://man.openbsd.org/acpibtn.4), it states if a value is set via `sysctl` it would react to acpi call.